# Mapping Hard Disk Image File to partition using command line

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, roaming-profile

I have a directory with hundreds of Hard Disk Image Files (.vhdx) - each containing user profile directory (C:\Users\xxx). When I click on a file using File Explorer, it is automatically mounted and I can access files inside. I have an issue with recreating the same with a command.

I do not know what is the username with given SID - I just need to modify a single file in each profile.

Example file: `E:\profiles\UVHD-S-1-5-21-1614895754-1035525444-839522115-21214.vhdx`

I've tried to use `net use`, `dism` and `subst` however I couldn't get any of those to work.

Comment: Once you know the command, Stack Overflow can help you automate it.  But finding the command is not a programming question.  Try SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708295(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`net use` is for mapping SMB shares, `dism` is for working with .wim images, `subst` is for mapping local paths to drive letters. Neither of them is suitable for working with VHD(X) files. Or claims to be, for that matter.

In more recent Windows versions (starting with Windows 8 IIRC) you have cmdlets like [`Mount-DiskImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/mount-diskimage) or [`Mount-VHD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/mount-vhd) for working with Hyper-V virtual harddisks. On Windows 7 you need to use [`diskpart.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770877.aspx).

Attach a virtual harddisk:

```
@'
select vdisk file="C:\path\to\your.vhdx"
attach vdisk
'@ | diskpart
```

Detach a virtual harddisk:

```
@'
select vdisk file="C:\path\to\your.vhdx"
detach vdisk
'@ | diskpart
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use `New-PSDrive` to manage this (although I do not have an ISO to test with):

```
New-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem' -Root 'path\to\container.vhdx' -Name 'vhd'
```

You can then access it like so:

```
Set-Location 'vdh:\Users\etc'
```

---

Edit:

Turns out there's an entire suite of commands to interact with Hyper-V.  I'd recommend [looking into this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v) and then [look through these commands](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559(v=wps.630).aspx)

There is a `Mount-VHD` cmdlet designed for exactly what you're trying to do.

*Note: these commands appear to be limited to Windows Server 2012+ and Windows 8+*